# UISplitViewController with TabBarController as detail view

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

Good evening,

I'm working in my first **universal** iOS app using **Swift 2** and I want to take advantages of larger screens, so I'd like to know if it is possible to use a **UISplitViewController** with a **TabBarController** as DetailView. The data model consist basically in a list of Events (master view) where each one contains several related information well differentiated in three types (detail view, one per tab). This is the actual Storyboard (click for full size):

[image: app storyboard]

If it's possible to implement this approach, there is a **"best practice"** way to do it? If not, **how do you implement a case like this**? I don't find any example which makes me think it's not the right approach.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Obviously it will work, I'm doing it in my app. I suggest you create a test project to experiment on how you want the primary view to work. But this is a sanctioned architecture.

Comment: @DavidH thanks for your comment. Are you saying that Apple will reject the app because the architecture?